# PDF generation from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cordova, pdf-generation, phonegap-build

I made an AngularJS page with multiple tables, and I need a pdf generation solution. I'm working in a Phonegap context.

The tools I found until now were not able to handle the CSS in my page (like JSpdf).

Do you know some great tools to solve my problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with JSpdf then?

Comment: I don't want to re-make my html page with jsPDF. I want to take the actual one and convert it to PDF. I just tried html2canvas but it doesn't keep my CSS (and convert my page to JPEG). It's complicated because I want to do this operation on client-side.

Comment: maybe you should show some code then

Comment: I have managed to make work jsPDF (with the fromHTML method). But how can I have some style in this ?[HTML Result](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img911/4294/oQA4Fo.png) and [jsPDF Result](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img540/1919/rXnHZa.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can try phantomJS. http://phantomjs.org
It provides print to pdf function too.

Comment: That's a great tool, but I need to make this conversion on client-side.